# How to extract the original coefficient instead of the t-statistic from adf.test?

Tags: r, statistics

In the [ADF-Test](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/tseries/html/adf.test.html) `adf.test` from the tseries package the t-statistic for a first order autoregressive coefficient equals one is computed and can be accessed via `statistic`.

Is there any possibility of extracting the *original coefficient* that was used in the t-test?

If this is not possible how can I use a different implementation of the ADF-test to access this information there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the code of the `adf.test` function: the coefficients are apparently not kept, but you can easily compute them yourself. There are many other implementations; you can check if they return more information:

```
library(sos)
???"Dickey-Fuller"
```

Answer (score 0):

That function returns a `htest` object which is just a list:

```
res <- adf.test(...
res$statistic
```

Comment: Thank you, so that gives me the t-statistic - but how do I get the *original coefficient* that what used for the t-test?